# Trying to keep MQTT client connection even when app is closed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mqtt, publish-subscribe

I am currently using MQTT protocol in my android app and I am able to receive messages when my app is open or when it is running in the background however when i close my app completely the connection is lost and I am not longer able to receive messages. I need to be able to still recieve messages as I want the message to trigger an activity in my app to launch. Here are the files that I am using to implement MQTT. MQTTHelper class: EDIT. Ive have tried to implement a service but it still doesnt seem to be working.Does Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
package com.example.carcrashdetection.helpers;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.DisconnectedBufferOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttActionListener;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;

public class MqttHelper extends Service {
        public MqttAndroidClient mqttAndroidClient;
         BroadcastReceiver m_ScreenOffReceiver;
        final String serverUri = "tcp://hairdresser.cloudmqtt.com:15767";

        final String clientId = "CarCrashDetection";
        final String subscriptionTopic = "Topic/+";

        final String username = "username";
        final String password = "password";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerReceiver();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MqttHelper.this.connect();
            }
        }).start();
    }
        public MqttHelper(Context context){
            mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(context, serverUri, clientId);
            mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {


                public void connectComplete(boolean b, String s) {


                }

                @Override
                public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
                    Log.w("Mqtt", mqttMessage.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {

                }
            });
            connect();
        }

        public void setCallback(MqttCallback callback) {
            mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(callback);
        }

        private void connect(){
            MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
            mqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
            mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(false);
            mqttConnectOptions.setUserName(username);
            mqttConnectOptions.setPassword(password.toCharArray());

            try {

                mqttAndroidClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {

                        DisconnectedBufferOptions disconnectedBufferOptions = new DisconnectedBufferOptions();
                        disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferEnabled(true);
                        disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferSize(100);
                        disconnectedBufferOptions.setPersistBuffer(false);
                        disconnectedBufferOptions.setDeleteOldestMessages(false);
                        mqttAndroidClient.setBufferOpts(disconnectedBufferOptions);
                        subscribeToTopic();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                        Log.w("Mqtt", "Failed to connect to: " + serverUri + exception.toString());

                    }
                });


            } catch (MqttException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        private void subscribeToTopic() {
            try {
                mqttAndroidClient.subscribe(subscriptionTopic, 0, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                        Log.w("Mqtt","Subscribed!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                        Log.w("Mqtt", "Subscribed fail!");
                    }
                });

            } catch (MqttException ex) {
                System.err.println("Exception whilst subscribing");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //do something
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void registerReceiver(){
        m_ScreenOffReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent){
                //Log.d(TAG,"onReceive of Wifi_State_Change called");
                if(intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION))
                {
                    int wifiState = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);
                    if(wifiState != WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED)
                        return;

                    final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                            String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();

                            Toast.makeText(context, "active wifi:" + ssid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            //You can connect to the your mqtt broker again:
                            connect();
                        }
                    }, 10000);
                }
            }
        };

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(m_ScreenOffReceiver, intentFilter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if(mqttAndroidClient!=null) {
        /*unregisterResources is needed,otherwise receive this error:
          has leaked ServiceConnection org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient*/
            try {
                mqttAndroidClient.unregisterResources();
                mqttAndroidClient.close();
                mqttAndroidClient.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        unregisterReceiver(m_ScreenOffReceiver);
        m_ScreenOffReceiver = null;

        super.onDestroy();
    }
    }
```

MainActivity

```
private void startMqtt(){
        mqttHelper = new MqttHelper(getApplicationContext());
        mqttHelper.setCallback(new MqttCallbackExtended(){
            @Override
            public void connectComplete(boolean b, String s) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "connected ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception{
                Log.e("message ", String.valueOf(mqttMessage));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Crash Occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, alert.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken){

            }
        });
    }
```

I've been searching for a while now but cant seem to find anything that works. I thought it would be an easy fix but its hasn't been for me. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you need to run the connection in a foreground service

Comment: could i extend Service in my helper class

Answer (score 0):

Your options will be to implement a server that will send your device push notifications and then your app can fetch the message once it is open again.

Alternatively you can implement a background service: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: could I extend Service on my helper class